# Change .htaccess to forbid spam links

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site got hacked and a bunch of links in a spammer-created `/up` sub-directory are getting a lot of hits.

I have cleared out the mess (a `.htaccess` rewrite and a `wp-stat.php` file, and now I would like to ignore/forbid all requests to the `/up` directory.

Currently I have a simple wordpress created .htaccess, but can't find a way of trapping requests to `/up` before the rewrite rules take over and give a 404 page from my wordpress theme.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your current code by this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/up(/.*|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will forbid all `/up` urls

Comment: That's not doing it. I still get a wordpress 404 page

Comment: What url are you trying to reach ?

Comment: as an example http://www.amsterdamfoodie.nl/up/bitdefender-antivirus-2011-32b-crack-till-2045.html

Comment: Well, this is weird. Are you sure your htaccess is executed (allowed in apache configuration) and *mod_rewrite* enabled ?

Comment: I think so, in as much as I rely upon .htaccess for pretty permalinks on my wordpress site